# How do I login to other sites, like Software Recommendations using my SO ID?

Tags: support

I want to log into Software Recommendations using my information from Meta Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow.

I have accounts on these sites:
Stack Overflow
Super User
Meta Stack Exchange
Game Development Stack Exchange
Stack Apps
Programmers Stack Exchange

I tried using my email address for Stack Overflow, but it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the openId providers that are associated with your account on any of the sites you mentioned.

You can find those out in your profile, by clicking on the "my logins" link:

> [image: my logins]

In whatever Stack Exchange site, go to the login page, then use of of those providers identified in the previous step (there is a "more log in options" link).

Log in to your openId provider, authorize the site (this happens on your provider site) and confirm the account creation on the Stack Exchange site.

The newly created account will get associated with your other accounts.